# pyqt- how to create clicked signal for QLabel class?

Tags: class, button, pyqt, signals, qlabel

i've created a image button class from QLabel. Now i wanna add a clicked signal to that. now, what to do?

```
 class PicButton(QLabel):

    def __init__(self,pixmap1,pixmap2,parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.pic = pixmap1
        imageSize = self.pic.size()
        imageSize.setWidth(imageSize.width()*.7)
        imageSize.setHeight(imageSize.height()*.7)
        self.pic = self.pic.scaled(imageSize,Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding)



        self.pic2 = pixmap2
        imageSize2 = self.pic2.size()
        imageSize2.setWidth(imageSize2.width()*.7)
        imageSize2.setHeight(imageSize2.height()*.7)
        self.pic2 = self.pic2.scaled(imageSize2,Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding)



    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setPixmap(self.pic2)
        event.accept()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        """ When the mouse leave this widget, destroy it. """
        self.setPixmap(self.pic)
        self.destroy()
```

i make a button :

```
  ImageButton2 = PicButton(QPixmap("image/buy.png"),QPixmap("image/buy_Hover.png"))
  ImageButton2.clicked.connect(self.addStuff)  # but this class has not  clicked signal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QLabels have no default `clicked` signal. If you want to have one, you must [add it](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal) yourself and emit it on the correct event.

To dectect the event you can:

- override [one or more of](http://qt-project.org/doc/qlabel.html#mousePressEvent)

  - QLabel.mouseDoubleClickEvent
  - QLabel.mousePressEvent
  - QLabel.mouseReleaseEvent
- [install](http://qt-project.org/doc/qobject.html#installEventFilter) an [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)
- Override QLabel.[event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qlabel.html#event)